# Find last row in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to take last row data from Column A to Column N
If i use the below script formula i get range from A2, not from last row

`var data = ws.getRange("A2:N" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();`

Please help me to get last row data

Answer (score 1):

**Getting the next available cell at the bottom of a column**

```
function lastRowInRangeWithData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange('A1:A');
  const lr = rg.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  Logger.log(lr);
}
```

[Range.getNextDataCell(Direction);](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction))

One of the problems with the above code is that if you have just one blank cell in a column it will give an incorrect result:

So for example:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 10 | 10 | 20 | 13 | 3 |
| 22 | 0 | 12 | 3 | 25 | 27 |
| 13 | 22 | 27 | 17 | 11 | 24 |
| 21 | 7 | 8 | 27 | 23 | 5 |
| 20 | 2 | 9 | 29 | 16 | 0 |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 24 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 24 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 26 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 23 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 26 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 26 |  |  |  |  |  |

The above function returns 9

The following function returns 19

```
function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse()
  let s=0;
  for(let i=0;i<rcA.length;i++) {
    if(rcA[i][0].toString().length==0) {
      s++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length-s;
}
```

And some people use this approach but it also has the problem of returning an incorrect result of 18 in this situation.

```
function lastRowInRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange('A1:A');
  const lr = rg.getDisplayValues().filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(lr);
}
```

The preceeding code returns 18

So I tend to stick with my getColumnHeight() function and there's a lot of ways to do it.

Here's one that uses the reduce method:

```
function getColumnHeightWReduce(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  return sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse().reduce(function(a,r){
    if(r[0].toString().length==0 && a.f==false){
      a.s++;
    }else{
      a.f=true;
    }
    return a;
  },{s:0,f:false,lr:sh.getLastRow(),height:function(){return this.lr-this.s;}}).height();
}
```

So if you don't have confidence that there won't ever be any blank cells some where in your column of data then you may want to be careful about calculating the column height.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to write `"A" + last_row` instead `"A2"` :

```
var last_row = ws.getLastRow();
var data = ws.getRange("A" + last_row + ":N" + last_row).getValues();
```